# not able to filter an nested record in find method and in populate method together

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i am trying to filter out a nested record based on my searchKey .for Example:
patient - >provider want to search a patient and an provider together based on searchKey.

But when i'm triggering searchkey with patient details it's working but when i put any keyword related to provider (want to search provider) but this time filter not working.
here is my code:

```
patients = await Patient.find({
                    $or: [
                        { firstName: { $regex: searchKey, $options: "i" } },
                        { lastName: { $regex: searchKey, $options: "i" } },
                        { socialSecurityNumber: { $regex: searchKey, $options: "i" } },
                    ],
                    provider: currentUser,
                }).populate({ path: "provider", select: "firstName lastName",  match : {
                        $or: [
                                {lastName: { $regex: searchKey,$options: "i" }},
                                {firstName: { $regex: searchKey,$options: "i" }},
                            ]
                    } })
                    .populate({ path: "gender", select: "name -_id" })
                    .skip(pageSize * pageNumber - pageSize)
                    .limit(pageSize).lean();
```